# Http Request - how to?

Tags: java, android, http

I have a service for http requst in web every 10 sec it run corectly and work perfectly but after a hour the app show erorr  **app unfortunately stop** and app not work here is my service. please see and Suggest me how it Resolve ?
Here is **Server.java**

```
public class Server extends Service {

    private static String TAG = "allstart";
    private Handler handler;
    private Runnable runnable;
    private final int runTime = 5000;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        handler = new Handler();
        runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {if (!isOnline(Server.this)){
             return;}

                String output=null;
                String url="http://localhost:8080/feed/appfeed.php";
                try {
                    output = new RequestTask().execute(url).get();
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }

                String withoutitlne = output.replaceAll("\\r|\\n", "");
                String input = withoutitlne.replace(" ", "");
                if (input != null && !input.isEmpty()) {
                String[] separated = output.split("\\*");
                String nb= separated[1].toString(); 
                    String am= separated[2].toString();
                    String oper= separated[0].toString(); 
                    String nnb = nb.replace(" ", "");
                    if (oper.indexOf("GP") >= 0) {

                        Intent newintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Recharge.class);
                        newintent.putExtra("rcnumber", nnb);
                        newintent.putExtra("rcamount", am);
                        newintent.putExtra("gpin", rb);
                        startService(newintent);
                    }               
                }
                handler.postDelayed(runnable, runTime);
            }
        };
        handler.post(runnable);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Task destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Server.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, myIntent, 0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager1 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
        alarmManager1.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Server.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, myIntent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager1 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
        alarmManager1.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);

    }

    class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android "+getAndroidVersion()+"; "+getDeviceName()+" Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/30.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36";    
            httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT, userAgent);

            HttpResponse response;
            String responseString = null;
            try {
                response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(uri[0]));
                StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();

                if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                    responseString = out.toString();
                    out.close();
                } else{
                    // Closes the connection.
                    response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                    throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
                }
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Handle problems..
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Handle problems..
            }
            return responseString;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            //Do anything with response..
        }    
    }

    public String getAndroidVersion() {
        String release = Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
        int sdkVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        return release ;
    }

    private boolean isOnline(Context mContext) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public String getDeviceName() {
        String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER;
        String model = Build.MODEL;
        return capitalize(model);
    }


    private String capitalize(String s) {
        if (s == null || s.length() == 0) {
            return "";
        }
        char first = s.charAt(0);
        if (Character.isUpperCase(first)) {
            return s;
        } else {
            return Character.toUpperCase(first) + s.substring(1);
        }
    } 

    public static String getPref(String key, Context context) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return preferences.getString(key, null);
    }
}
```

My target Device above 4.0 version.

Comment: Could you please add the stacktrace

Comment: catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            //TODO Handle problems..
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //TODO Handle problems..
        } replace //TODO Handle problems.. with e.printStackTrace();

Comment: where i add it please edit my code with your solution.

Comment: You need to get the logs for the crash in order to figure out the cause of the crash.

Comment: lost network conection time of http request then show error